# Is there any way to access MSMQ public queue if not on domain?

Tags: dns, msmq

The solution is crying out for the MSMQ solution but unfortunately the posting service is not on the domain. Is there anyway to post to the public queue that is on the domain from the machine in the DMZ?

I could use a webservice to post but this is a extra component to maintain. The database table is the alternative solution but again it is not the ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is. By using the "[format name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700996(VS.85).aspx)". You will still have issues with [firewall](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183293), which is not trivial, and authentication.

A good resource is [MSMQ from the plumber's mate](http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/)